# Does a 68 pin QFN connector go by another name?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, bluetooth, asus-laptop, laptop-repair

**Background:** The WIFI on an Asus 541UV-DM884T laptop is sketchy so I would like to replace the card. The card itself is a [RealTek RTL8723BE](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8723be). The laptop only has a single antenna going to the card. It has the latest updates.

**Goal:**
I would like to swap the card out for an Intel WIFI/Bluetooth card or something with comparably good drivers and preferably supported in Linux.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

*Update:* Here is a picture of the card, both sides, and how it was situated in the laptop. What type of connection is it? Is there anything on the card itself which indicates the type of connection?

[image: WIFI card, both sides]

Comment: Not sure you can. Most slimline laptops are just a single motherboard with all components soldered/integrated, including the WiFi.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, I have already removed the WIFI/Bluetooth card while inspecting the laptop for loose connections. It's a lower mid-range laptop with discrete WIFI/Bluetooth, RAM, and hard drive components.

Answer (score 0):

A 68 pin QFN is a `68 Lead Quad Flat No-Lead Plastic Package (QFN)`.

***However, you cannot simply remove one WiFi chip and replace it with another, even if they come in the same package.***

There is no guarantee that the power, data, and ground lines run at compatible voltage and/or are located in the same pin positions.  Replacing one chip for another could result in damaging your new chip and/or your laptop.

You are *far* better off disabling the onboard WiFi and using an external USB WiFi dongle.

Comment: There may have been some confusion on my part. I am referring to a discrete card in the laptop and not the chip on it. The model information I gave was from the card itself and the link is the result of my search for it. It's been years since I've tried to replace a laptop WIFI card so I don't know what the current connection types are. I'll try to upload pictures to clarify.